# Perl -pi -e 's/ / /' filename not working inside perl script. but it working in command line

Tags: perl

I have a perl script, in that script I need to replace a string in every line of file. I used below line inside that perl script. It shows a syntax error near `-pi -e`. What am I doing wrong?

```
perl -pi -e 's/ / /' filename
```

I have a pipe delimited file to be used in perl script. am using that file contents to be loaded into table using BCP. I have created the table with 8 clomuns, but pipe delimited file has only 7 columns. In that file i need to add '| ' (pipe followed by space) symbol at the end of every record. So that it will match the number of columns in both table and BCP file. Hence in part of the perl script i need to use 's/$/\| /' concept. but i like to do this in single line itself inside the perl script. (like perl -pi -e 's/$/\| /' which is working in command line)

Answer (score 4):

The command-line code is written for the *shell* to parse before it passes control to the `perl` compiler/interpreter program.

We can use the [`B::Deparse`](https://metacpan.org/module/B%3a%3aDeparse) backend processor to see what Perl code is being executed like this

```
$perl -MO=Deparse -pi -e 's/ / /' filename
```

and it shows the equivalent Perl program to be

```
BEGIN { $^I = ""; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    s/ / /;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

We can drop the `BEGIN` block as long as we make sure `$^I` is defined *first*. The label `LINE` can go because it is never used. We can also avoid the check on the success of `print`. Together with some syntax conveniences that Perl allows in real-life code, we get this

```
$^I = "";
while (<>) {
    s/ / /;
    print;
}
```

But why are you replacing every space with another space before printing?!

Comment: Judging from the question, I don't think it's that helpful to bring up `B::Deparse` which is a pretty advanced tool.

Comment: Generally a good answer, but particularly like the last line.

Comment: @doubleDown: Helpful to know what is actually happening though.  Which is the essence of their problem, a lack of comprehension of what is going on.

Comment: @doubleDown: I'm not explaining how to use `B:Deparse`, I'm explaining that the command-line program is equivalent to a Perl script.

Comment: I have a pipe delimited file to be used in perl script. am using that file contents to be loaded into table using BCP. I have created the table with 8 clomuns, but pipe delimited file has only 7 columns. In that file i need to add '| ' (pipe followed by space) symbol at the end of every record. So that it will match the number of columns in both table and BCP file. Hence in part of the perl script i need to use 's/$/\| /' concept. but i like to do this in single line itself inside the perl script. (like perl -pi -e 's/$/\| /' which is working in command line)

Answer (score 3):

The line is shell command. Not perl script. This line calls perl and gives it program:

```
s/ / /
```

Plus sets certain options (-p, -i), but it is still *shell* program call, not Perl expression.

Comment: I have a pipe delimited file to be used in perl script. am using that file contents to be loaded into table using BCP. I have created the table with 8 clomuns, but pipe delimited file has only 7 columns. In that file i need to add '| ' (pipe followed by space) symbol at the end of every record. So that it will match the number of columns in both table and BCP file. Hence in part of the perl script i need to use 's/$/\| /' concept. but i like to do this in single line itself inside the perl script. (like perl -pi -e 's/$/\| /' which is working in command line)